# How do I prevent exceptions from half-loaded pages' form submission while using asp.net event validation?

Tags: asp.net, eventvalidation

I have a page with some dynamically added buttons. If you click a button before the page has fully loaded, it throws the classic exception:

> ```
> Invalid postback or callback argument. 
> Event validation is enabled using in configuration or in a page. For
> ```
>
> security purposes, 
>       this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the 
>       server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid
>   and expected, use 
>       the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the 
>       postback or callback data for validation.

I am guessing the Viewstate field hasn't loaded on the form yet, the the other bits are being submitted. What's the best way to prevent this error, while maintaining Event Validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140303/aspnet-unable-to-validate-data#254581). To quote:

Essentially, you'll want to get the ViewState to load at the top of the page. In .NET 3.5 SP1 the *RenderAllHiddenFieldsAtTopOfForm* property was added to the PagesSection configuration.

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>

    <system.web>

        <pages renderAllHiddenFieldsAtTopOfForm="true"></pages>

    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Interestingly, the default value of this is true. So, in essence, if you are using .NET 3.5 SP1 then the ViewState is automatically being rendered at the top of the form (before the rest of the page is loaded) thus eliminating the ViewState error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this to be caused more often by the `__EVENTVALIDATION` field than the ViewState not being loaded.  The `__EVENTVALIDATION` is at the bottom of the page and if it hasn't been received by the client when the user causes a postback you will get that exception.

I've not yet found a great solution, but what I usually do on pages that tend to cause this due to large amounts of content is to wire up the buttons to a javascript function that checks an isLoaded var that only gets set to true in the document.ready call.  If isLoaded is false it silently eats the event, if it's true it lets if go through.  This is a pain to set up, but it has ended most of my invalid postback issues.

Comment: you are right, it is the event validation field. this is fixed in 3.5 apparently.

Answer (score 0):

What if you set those button's visible property to false by default and at the end of the page load or event validation you set their visible property to true?  This way restricting them from clicking the button until the page has fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the ViewState is loaded right after the form tag on the page.

Have you tried using `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation( button.UniqueID )` for each button after you add the button to the page?  Depending on where you add the button, the event hookup for the page may have already happened and thus the events generated by the button may not be registered with the page.

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a long time trying to figure out why the __EVENTVALIDATION tag renders at the bottom on a particular site but towards the top on every other website. I eventually figured out it was because of code in the Render override event. That, along with a lean viewstate mostly got rid of this error but just for good measure I added the logic below on the button that was causing the error:

**javascript somewhere on the page**

```
function CheckForHiddenFields()
{
    var EventValidation = document.getElementById('__EVENTVALIDATION');
    if (EventValidation && EventValidation.value && EventValidation.value != '')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Add attribute to asp:Button:**

```
OnClientClick="return CheckForHiddenFields();"
```